# No file Minimalexample.toc

Tags: table-of-contents, miktex, latexmk

I use MikTex 22.7. Something is wrong with my Latex installation. I try to create a table of contents in my minimal example but the compilation process aborts with the following error message:

```
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.
Latexmk: Missing input file 'Minimalexample.toc' (or dependence on it) from following:
  'No file Minimalexample.toc.'
```

But the minimalexample.toc is created and is located in the directory.
I have reinstalled miktex a few times, but without success.

I still add my minimal example and the complete output trace

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{obsblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.42,0.7}
\definecolor{obsyellow}{rgb}{1,0.79,0.165}
\definecolor{obsdarkblue}{rgb}{0.09,0.286,0.580}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{enhanced,
before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm,
colback=obsyellow!30,colframe=obsdarkblue,boxrule=0.8mm,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
boxed title style={frame code={
\path[fill=tcbcolback!30!black]
([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
\path[left color=tcbcolback!60!black,right color=tcbcolback!60!black,
middle color=tcbcolback!80!black]
([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
[rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
-- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
-- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
[sharp corners]-- cycle;
},interior engine=empty,
},
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title={#2},#1}



\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
        \section[Homework Collection]{Homework Collection}
        \subsection[Electricity theory]{Electricity theory}
        \begin{mybox}[colbacktitle=obsblue]{Electricity theory}
            description
        \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

output trace

```
############################################################
Win CP console initial and current in/out Win: (850, 65001), (1252, 1252)
Coding system for system and terminal: 'CP1252'
---
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Mar. 2022. Version 4.77, version: 4.77.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
  //fileserver/users/Username/Desktop/Minimalexample/Minimalexample.tex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
  pdflatex
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  --max-print-line=10000 -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder  "//fileserver/users/Username/Desktop/Minimalexample/Minimalexample.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.8.28) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(//fileserver/users/Username/Desktop/Minimalexample/Minimalexample.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-30> (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/exam\exam.cls
Document Class: exam 2021/02/26 Version 2.7 by Philip Hirschhorn
(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size12.clo))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex-dev/graphics\mathcolor.ltx)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/varwidth\varwidth.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/colortbl\colortbl.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\array.sty)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcolorbox.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\verbatim.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/environ\environ.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/trimspaces\trimspaces.sty)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbraster.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbraster.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbskins.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskins.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbbreakable.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbbreakable.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/oberdiek\pdfcol.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbhooks.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbhooks.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbtheorems.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbtheorems.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbfitting.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbfitting.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcblistingsutf8.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingsutf8.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcblistings.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistings.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/listings\listings.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/listings\lstmisc.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/listings\listings.cfg)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcblistingscore.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingscore.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbprocessing.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbprocessing.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty)))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/listingsutf8\listingsutf8.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/stringenc\stringenc.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty)))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbexternal.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbexternal.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbmagazine.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbmagazine.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbvignette.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbvignette.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryfadings.code.tex))) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbposter.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbposter.code.tex' version '5.1.1'
)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def) (Minimalexample.aux) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty)
No file Minimalexample.toc.
[1{C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
This exam contains 0 questions with 0 parts, 0 subparts, and 0 subsubparts.
This exam has a total of 0 points.
This exam has a total of 0 bonus points.

Class exam Warning: Point totals have changed. Rerun to get point totals right.

(Minimalexample.aux) )<C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on Minimalexample.pdf (1 page, 35001 bytes).
SyncTeX written on Minimalexample.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Minimalexample.log.
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.
Latexmk: Missing input file 'Minimalexample.toc' (or dependence on it) from following:
  'No file Minimalexample.toc.'
----------------------
This message may duplicate earlier message.
Latexmk: Failure in processing file '//fileserver/users/Username/Desktop/Minimalexample/Minimalexample':
   *LaTeX didn't generate the expected log file 'Minimalexample.log'
----------------------
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (850,65001)
Latexmk: Getting log file 'Minimalexample.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'Minimalexample.log'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'Minimalexample.pdf'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: gave an error
```

Comment: The warning about the `.toc` file is likely not the main problem. This file does not exist at the start of the first run (because it is created during that run), Latexmk just notices this and uses this information to start a second run, this is the normal/expected behavior from Latexmk. The real problem is that there is another error that prevents the first run from being completed. It could be a file permission problem or something in the code or in the installation that causes this error.

Comment: To diagnose you could use the Windows Command prompt to start pdflatex manually on your file and see if any errors are reported, either on screen or in the .log file if that is created. If that works without problems then you can try latexmk from the command prompt to see if you can get some more information there.

Comment: @Z.J Latexmk maintainer here. If you are still having problems, contact me at the address in the latexmk documentation.  There are a number of strange things in the output from latexmk, and it will be too difficult to debug the problems through an exchange of comments like this.

Comment: I just found out that the command latexmk and pdflatex work without errors in the Command Promt. I use the Visual Studio Code Extension to compile them. Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Then do contact me directly, as I suggested.  Once we've got things sorted out, we can report back here.